# PHP Syntax to shorten if-statements

Tags: php

Disclaimer : the following is a bad practice (but it would be useful in a very, very specific use)

Is there a way to shorten (in a not-so-nice-way-but-shorter) if statements :
instead of  :

```
if(5 == $foo){
   $b = 98;
   $c = 98 * $otherVariable;
   //do something complex
   doSomethingElse($b, $c);
}
```

This example would become shorter, even if it is formatted by an IDE.
It would become something like that (but this does not work):

```
(5 == $foo) && { $b = 98;
   $c = 98 * $otherVariable;
   //do something complex
   doSomethingElse($b, $c);}
```

Comment: why `&&` is there?

Comment: It should be shorter, still readable, but I guess uglier. It is to be used just on specific cases, not in all the code !

Comment: @AlivetoDie remember the old-style "mysql_connect() or die() " ?? It's like "mysql_connect() || die()" ..., the || has a similar style to the && here. The && says "execute the code if the first statement is true".

Comment: Why does this need to be any shorter? If those are the steps you need to do (conditionally set `$b`, `$c` and call a function), then this is pretty much the optimal number of lines for it.

Comment: @deceze Some of my block of codes needs to be as short as possible, as they are not part of the main fundamental logic. It's really specific.

Comment: Then consider moving those blocks into another function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any decent IDE can allow you to write macros. But generally if you're writing code in PHP **you must use the PHP language syntax**

Comment: **Bad practice**, it does not make you any smart than other developers coding in short formats, it just makes your code harder to read and to maintain, **write clean human readable code**!

Comment: @teeyo I know it is a bad practice - not to worry about that. In the actual case where I need something shorter, it is *actually* to get something more clean and human readable - it's one case in one million. Just like when people used to write mysql_connect() or die();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, you should opt for **better readable code**, but still if you want to do something different, you may go through below :

```
($foo == 5) && doSomethingElse(98, 98*$otherVariable);
```

OR

**PHP Ternary Operator**

```
($your_boolean) ? 'This is  true' : 'This is false';
```

You can rewrite your `if` statement like below :

```
($foo == 5) ? doSomethingElse(98, 98*$otherVariable) : "";

// little shorter but not better readable
($foo != 5) ? :  doSomethingElse(98, 98*$otherVariable);
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
function aa(){ echo "123\n"; }

$foo = 5;

// this will not call aa()
($foo == 4) && aa()  ;

// this will call aa()
($foo == 5) && aa() ;
?>

$ php test.php
123
```

Comment: `if (...) ...` vs. `... ? ... : ""`… Uhm, yeah, no…

Comment: @deceze: I too prefer `if(){} else{}` like you,  but OP wants something different, what else can be done, so suggested, you are right

Comment: I mean… it's not even shorter. In fact, it's two *more* characters.

Comment: @deceze: Oh yeah, true, probably  `($foo != 5) ? :  doSomethingElse(98, 98*$otherVariable);`

Comment: If you don't need an `else`, then you don't need a *ternary* ("ternary" = *three parts*). `&&` will do just fine.

Comment: @deceze  true, I agree

Comment: I really don't see the point: Instead of `if` before the condition you use `&&` or `?:` after so you have no change in length unless you remove the parenthesis (2 characters won!) and the variables the OP has set / modified will not have been set / modified.

Comment: Yes you are right, infact its not better readable as well as what OP gonna do by saving 2 chars !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(5 == $foo) doSomethingElse(98, 98*$otherVariable);
```

Look out! The variables `$b` and `$c` are not available for further calculations!